# Тест на скорость загрузки сайта

Tags: javascript, css

Похожие вопросы уже искал, ответа не нашел.

Осталось исправить последнюю ошибку Google Page Speed, а именно:

**Удалите код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение верхней части страницы**

Вот на какие файлы ругается гугол: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
На сколько я понял, нужно убрать ссылки на эти файлы из <хеад> и поставить их перед закрывающим боди.

Вот что у меня в хед: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Я выполнил этот шаг,убрал все это перед закрывающим боди. но теперь во первых, поплыли стили, во вторых ошибка не исправилась. Вернул обратно в хед, до выяснения обстоятельств.

Или что-то нужно сделать с самими файлами на которые ругается гугол?

Answer (score 1):

1. Подключая шрифты через googleapis вы получаете множество тормозящих редиректов внутри этого сервиса. Нужно разместить шрифты на сайте локально.
2. Переместите подключение css в конец файла html. Можно просто тег `<link>` разместить, но если вам важна валидность когда используйте js, размещенный в конце html, для формирования тега `<link>` с css-кодом в секции `<head>`
3. Воспользуйтесь сервисом critical path css, для формирования css-кода критически важного для отображения верхней 1000 пикселей сайта, и разместите этот код инлайн, в секции `<head>` между тегами `<style></style>`.
4. Если какой-либо js-код используются, только когда пользователь совершил какие-то явные действия на сайте, например нажал кнопку, не надо грузить это js сразу при загрузке страницы. Грузите его только когда нажата кнопка.

Когда это сделаете можно будет дальше думать как ускорить загрузку сайта.

Comment: Вы считаете что подключать шрифты которые скорее всего уже лежат в кэше браузера медленнее чем подключать локальные шрифты?

Comment: А что размещение шрифтов локально запрещает браузеру пользоваться кэшем?

Comment: Вы советуете отказаться от шрифтов которые с высокой вероятностью уже в кеше. Локальных шрифтов в кэше браузера при **первой** загрузке сайта точно нет. Так что вероятность того что даже самый не популярный гугловский шрифт окажется в кэше браузера, выше. И про какие редиректы идет речь? Ссылка возвращает css.

Comment: Сделайте сами как вы хотите и приведите результат в page speen insights. Мой опыт показывает что подключение на страницу, где нет ничего кроме одного абзаца текста шрифта, например Roboto Regular (Latin) через googleapis дает 75 из 100 попугаев, подключение шрифта локально на той же странице 100 из 100. Относительно редиректов, да, может я неверно выразился, но как вы думаете, ваш сайт один стучится к googleapis? Вы хотите, чтобы ваш сайт был поставлен в очередь, пока все запросы не будут последовательно отработаны. К тому же апи отдает не только css, но и сами шрифты. И все это через очередь.